# Current TimeWindow contains elements from previous TimeWindow

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have two DataStreams.

First DataStream **stream1** aggregates data into 1 minute windows.

```
DataStream<T> stream1 = input
    .keyBy(t -> t.id)
    .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(60)))
    .aggregate(new SomeAggregate());
```

stream1 produces the following windows

| Window Id | Window Start | Window End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:59:00.000 | 00:59:59.999 |
| 2 | 00:00:00.000 | 00:00:59.999 |
| 3 | 00:01:00.000 | 00:01.59.999 |
| 4 | 00:02:00.000 | 00:02.59.999 |
| 5 | 00:03:00.000 | 00:02.59.999 |
| 6 | 00:04:00.000 | 00:04.59.999 |
| n | ... | ... |

Second DataStream **stream2** aggregates **stream1** data into 5 minute windows/aggregations.

```
DataStream<T> stream2 = stream1
    .keyBy(t -> t.id)
    .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(300)))
    .aggregate(new SomeAggregate());
```

stream2 produces the following windows

| Window Id | Window Start | Window End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:55:00.000 | 00:59:59.999 |
| 2 | 00:00:00.000 | 00:04:59.999 |
| n | ... | ... |

**Question** -

How come the following stream2 window

| Window Id | Window Start | Window End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:00:00.000 | 00:04:59.999 |

Contains **00:59:00.000 - 00:59:59.999** (Id 1) window from stream1?

| Window Id | Window Start | Window End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **00:59:00.000** | **00:59:59.999** |
| 2 | 00:00:00.000 | 00:00:59.999 |
| 3 | 00:01:00.000 | 00:01.59.999 |
| 4 | 00:02:00.000 | 00:02.59.999 |
| 5 | 00:03:00.000 | 00:02.59.999 |

Shouldn't **00:59:00.000 - 00:59:59.999** window belong to 00:55:00.000 - 00:59:59.999 stream2 window?

I was expecting to see these windows instead.

| Window Id | Window Start | Window End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 00:00:00.000 | 00:00:59.999 |
| 3 | 00:01:00.000 | 00:01.59.999 |
| 4 | 00:02:00.000 | 00:02.59.999 |
| 5 | 00:03:00.000 | 00:02.59.999 |
| 6 | 00:04:00.000 | 00:04.59.999 |

So I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Given start X and end Y, I only want to see windows that had start and end time between X and Y, not older or newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are using processing time windows.

The window for 00:59:00.000 to 00:59:59.999 for stream1 is being triggered as soon as the system clock reaches 01:00:00.000. By the time this window result reaches the second window, the time is at least 01:00:00.000, and so this result becomes part of the later window.

To get consistent, deterministic results, use event time windows (in combination with watermarks).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I appreciate it. If I am not wrong, the idea is to use assignTimestampsAndWatermarks along with WatermarkStrategy (before) keyBy in stream1 along with TumblingEventTimeWindows.

Comment: Yes, that should do it.

Comment: My sincere apologies for another question. Say I have keyed 5 minute TumblingEventTimeWindow of 00:00:00-00:04:59.999. It receives some event with timestamp of 00:01:00. From what I understand, the window will only produce results once I get an event with timestamp higher than 00:04:59.999. Which means technically, it is possible for the window to never produce any results.

Comment: Event time windows only produce results when triggered by a watermark. So yes, a window might never produce any results. Note, however, that if the job is (1) run with bounded inputs or (2) stopped with the "drain" option then before being shutdown a final very large watermark is automatically produced that will close all open windows.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I thought I was misunderstanding and/or missing something.

Comment: Just a note if someone ever reads this - you can write your own Watermark generator to avoid cases when all partitions are idle.